# I get a constant for the whole raster by subtracting two rasters in R

Tags: r, raster

I have two raster in brick format, as a result of previous operations, they have the same characteristics. When I try to make a simple subtraction between the two, it gives me a constant in all my study area. when I do other operations like multiply, add or divide it works perfectly, but not with subtraction. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

reading the previous queries I have tried replacing NA values, with different raster formats and nothing. the input values of the subtraction are obtained by different functions.

```
Rtoa_B1 <- Rtoa_F(d, RadianceB1, Eo,Us)
Rsuperf_B1 <- Rsuperf_F(RadianceB1,Lr1,Tv,Eo,d,Oz,Tz,Edown)
Ratm <- Rtoa_B1 - Rsuperf_B1
```

the classes of the obtained files are

```
> Rtoa_B1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : B1_MOD02HKM.A2019001.1605.061.2019002013822 
min values :                                  0.08510739 
max values :                                   0.3040431 

> Rsuperf_B1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : B1_MOD02HKM.A2019001.1605.061.2019002013822 
min values :                                   0.0617993 
max values :                                    0.280735 

> Ratm
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0.02330808, 0.02330808  (min, max)
```

the functions

```
Rsuperf_F <- function(radiance,Lr,Tv,Eo,d,Oz,Tz,Edown){
  
  return((pi*(radiance-Lr)*(d**2))/(Tv*((Eo*cos(Oz)*Tz)+Edown)))
}
Rtoa_F <- function(d,radiance,Eo,Us){
  
  return(  (pi*(d**2)*radiance)/(Eo*Us)   )
}
```

function values are previously calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious reason would be that the difference between the two rasters is the same for all cells. With multiply and divide you would not notice that.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- b + 10
d <- x - b
d
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : red, green, blue 
#min values :  10,    10,   10 
#max values :  10,    10,   10
```

If that is not the case than please edit your question to illustrate that.

From your edits I see the range between the min and max values is the same for both layers.

```
0.08510739  - 0.0617993
#[1] 0.02330809
0.3040431 - 0.280735 
#[1] 0.0233081
```

I cannot see if these values are for the same cells, but this is all the information you provide. So far it suggest that computation is correct.

Since your rasters are really small, you can do `values(Rtoa_B1) - values(Rsuperf_B1)` and I expect that you will see that you will only get values of `0.0233081`

Comment: thanks for answering. the constant value I get is the subtraction of the minimum values (0.0212086). raster cell values are in the range (0 - 1). No, they are not the same. what seems very strange to me is that all arithmetic operations work except subtraction. the files are of type:> class(Rtoa_B1) [1] "RasterBrick" attr(,"package") [1] "raster"

Comment: I have expanded my answer based on your edits.

Comment: your answer is correct. I never thought that the differences would be the same for the other variables that affect the Rsuperf_F function. I can review where the methodological error is. Thank you for your attention